# Android and Node.js Socket.io not working

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

After following the examples. i am unable to send a message from my android application to my server. here is my code.

Server

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on("event", function(msg){
    console.log("Hello_world");
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Android (Client)

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.sockket(ServerEndpoints.EMULATOR_LOCALHOST_SERVER_ENDPOINT);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e)
    }
}


mSocket.connect();
mSocket.emit("event", "Hello World");
```

this code was pulled almost word for word from the example. so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information on what is going wrong? What error messages or other output? Remark: you code says IO.sockket instead of IO.socket. I assume that is a typo.

Comment: yep typo. I receive no output or error whatsover.